# SonarQube analysis fails with error 500

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I use sonarqube 5.6.1 for analysis, My jenkins build fails with the below error,
This does't happen all time,
I have been googling whole day and couldn't find a solution, has someone come across this? Any idea or suggestions to solve this.

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project parent-pom: Error 500 on http://xxxx.com:8085/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=110903732 -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: HTTP 500 means server error. Look at the logs on the SonarQube server side (in `<sonar_install_dir>/logs/sonar.log`) when the error occurs on the client side. Then update your question with your findings.

Comment: This is the error reported in sonar log,

2016-10-27T13:20:22.468619Z 350 [Note] Aborted connection 350 to db: 'sonar56' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Comment: That's the error to investigate further. Then update your question with your findings (and/do provide full log excerpts rather than tiny snippets without context).